# Animations in Unity are not working properly

Tags: unity, animation, blender, mecanim

I've done a few animations in Blender for my 3D character but the problem is, that they look different in Unity. It seems like the eyes are moving too much. I tried to change many things in import like rig etc. but nothing helped at all. Here are screenshots:

[Wrong animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kowc497maty7gmi/bad.gif?dl=0)

[image]

[Good animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/odk0lcj6r9ihvbv/good.gif?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GameDev StackExchange! You might want to upload your gifs to imgur and link the gif in your question, or use the built-in "add image" button shown when creating/editing a question ;)

Comment: What exactly "looks different" in Unity? Have you made sure to tune your model's import settings ( `Animation Type` -> Humanoid etc...) to see if anything changed?

Comment: Another possible issue might be that your rig is such that the head's vertices are influenced by more than 4 bones (or more than the number that's set in your quality settings). So you might want to check what's set in your Quality Settings under Blend Weights: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html

Comment: I tried different rig settings and generic gives the best result, humanoid is much worse and I already use 4 bones on the mesh. For me, it seems like an issue with weights which are not imported correctly from blender or 4 bones is not enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved that problem by simplifying his head's armature and using .blend file in unity.

By simplifying I meant removing most of head's bones but leaving just one.
[image: Good]

[image: Bad]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer will likely be more useful for other devs facing similar problems if you edit it to explain what you did to simplify the armature, and how that helped.

Comment: The system has flagged your answer as low-quality because of its length and content. As a basic guideline, your answer should contain enough information to help someone else solve this problem. Also, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted.